# Is there a Matlab equivalent to Python's xarray?

Tags: python, matlab, python-xarray

I've been flicking back and forth between Python and Matlab for various geoscience projects and generally find the structure of Matlab easier for modelling purposes, however, Python has some really neat packages that I can't seem to find equivalents of in Matlab.

Does anyone know if there is a Matlab equivalent to xarray (xarray.pydata.org)? This would be super helpful for organising and indexing my full data set in 3-dimensional space.

I'm looking for something that allows Matlab arrays to be indexed and stacked together into one object.

Cheers

Comment: There are many ways in which you can achieve similar things, depending on which features are most important for you to keep (3d arrays, structs, tables, custom classes ...). Also, instead of looking for equivalents, perhaps you can directly use `xarray` in MATLAB through the [Python interface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-python-from-matlab.html).

Comment: Thanks yes I did think about using xarray through a Python interface, but as I'm running 1,000s of loops I'm concerned about the additional run time of constantly passing arrays back and forth. Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked *cell* in MatLab?
It is a collection of matrices where you can access them with index.

```
num = 5;
your_cell = cell(num,1);
your_cell{i} = your_mat
```